SharePoint On-Prem issue with documents
We are using SharePoint 2019 on-prem, and are running into an issue where documents in a document library are showing an error message when clicking on the document.  The error message says, "Error
Failed to load PDF document.".
What would cause this issue?  We recently migrated to MS365, so I wonder if it's an issue with the version of Adobe Reader?  Or is there a setting I can do to the document library to resolve this issue?
Previously, we were told to clear the cache, but that worked temporarily.  I need to figure out what the issue is to fix this permanently.

There will be no problem opening PDF in M365. You can choose to open the file in the browser or in the App (you can choose the App you want to open the file in).
Open in the browser:


Open in the App:


Thanks, but I only have the "Open in browser" option when opening a document from SharePoint.  Even though we've transitioned to M365, we are still using the on-prem version of SharePoint.  We are not using SharePoint Online.
